# Reverse for 'post_shareing' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When i click on Share this Post in show_more.html , this error is raised.

show_more.html

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'mains:post_share' post.id %}">Share This Post</a>
</p>
```

urls.py

```
path('<int:post_id>/share/',views.post_share,name='post_share'),
```

views.py

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=post_id, status='published')


    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

    else:
        form = EmailPost()

    return render(request, 'mains/post_share.html', {'post':post,'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
class EmailPost(forms.Form):
    name_subject = forms.CharField(max_length=400)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    description = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: Did you use :-

<a href="{% url 'mains:post_share' post.id %}">Share This Post</a>

Comment: Yes i did it but it showed me this error :- Reverse for 'post_share' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/share/$']

Comment: Please help in this SIR.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when the url reference in your html file does not match with any paths in your urls.py file.

In urls.py:

```
path('post_share/<int:post_id>',views.post_share,name='post_share'),
```

This should solve your current problem. It is a good practice to show your error stack trace when asking questions.

Comment: Sir i've edited this . same error is raised. Please help sir